# Readonly filesytem and "Unable to resolve host"

Tags: raspberrypi

My raspberry PI is running Ubuntu 18.04 (64 bit). Anytime I run a command with sudo I get:

`sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Resource temporarily unavailable`

and you may think: **"Well, just edit your /etc/hosts file blah blah"**

But my filesystem is readonly, I can't save files because my hostname is messed up neither can I fix it because to remove readonly I need sudo.

Kinda done with Ubuntu, this is the 3rd time and its really frustrating to have to re-install the whole OS because of this.

`$ sudo nano /etc/hosts
[File '/etc/hosts' is unwritable]`

`$ sudo fsck -Af -M
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Resource temporarily unavailable`

`$ sudo mount -o remount /
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Resource temporarily unavailable`

Comment: Can you post the output of `mount`?

Comment: Looks like you need another Linux machine to fix both the host file and the file system. This is what happens when computers run OSs. :~)

Comment: It sounds like you have more than one problem. It sounds like you've been "tinkering" with the standard Ubuntu install. Standard Ubuntu installs don't have these problems. You may also have a hard disk problem... use the `Disks` app to check your SMART data.

Comment: I have this exact same problem, haven't messed with the kernel at all, just installed it and a 4 years later this error pops up